# prior art proof

Tags: claims, priority

I filed a provisional application in 1994 . Then i sent a full description of my invention to an eminent professor in the field of that invention in USA, soon after filing the provisional application , describing it in full details , mentioning the date and number of my provisional application in the patent office of my country; but she didn’t like the idea , seemingly , and she sent later al letter hoping me good luck and that she has no expertise in that branch of the innovation. In 2015 , accidently i read that a team of scientists in USA has discovered a new way for treatment of certain serious cases and surprisingly, that discovery was my invention typically , although they used it for different microbes ; it was the same device that i invented in 1994 . Is there any way to prove that i am the first inventor ?

Comment: can you elaborate if your provisional was converted to complete and published?

Comment: It was never converted to non - provisional application and I don't know if at tha time the same rules were applied about publication but that's why my very question " would that letter be considered as publication and hence the later invention would be obvious or not novel ".